# How to create a Hash that includes a dynamically build array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I need to create something like this:

```
"paxReference" => [{
  "ptc" => "ADT",                 
  "traveller" => [
    {
      "ref" => "1"               
    },
    { 
      "ref" => "2"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "ptc" => "CH",                 
  "traveller" => [
    {
      "ref" => "3",                 
    },
    {
      "ref" => "4",                
    }
  ]
},
]
```

But the array of hashes "traveller" must be built dynamically, I mean, If a pararmeter ADT_number is 4, I must include 4

```
"ref" => "1"
"ref" => "2"
"ref" => "3"
"ref" => "4"
```

Same thing for the "CH" segment.

How can I do this in Ruby?

The out put should look like this:

```
<paxReference>
 <ptc>ADT</ptc>
 <traveller>
  <ref>1</ref>
 </traveller>
 <traveller>
  <ref>2</ref>
 </traveller>
</paxReference>
<paxReference>
 <ptc>CH</ptc>
 <traveller>
  <ref>3</ref>
 </traveller>
 <traveller>
  <ref>4</ref>
 </traveller>
</paxReference>
```

Comment: What exactly is the input and output here?

Comment: Look at my edit... Input? I just get two parameters: the number of ADT (Adult) ref I need to include and the number of CH (children) ref I have to add.

Comment: Why bother making a hash if you just want some markup?  Just write your markup with a program and skip the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
paxReference = ptcs.map do |ptc|
  out_hash = {}
  out_hash["ptc"] = ptc
  out_hash["traveler"] = ADT_number.times.map {|i| {"ref" => i }}
end
```

This is in the case that ptcs is an array, and that ADT_number doesn't change for each one.  If ADT_number changes, then you'll want to grab something with an index or something like that.

Comment: Apparently you've edited how you want your output.  That is not a conventional output for a hash.  You can write an output function to accomplish that, but I get the feeling that something fundamental to helping you with this might be missing.

Comment: I'm building a SOAP request using Savon